# What is the probability that the number $3^a+7^b$ has a digit equal to $8$ at the units place?

Tags: probability, number-theory

The number $a$ is randomly selected from the set $\left\{0,1,2,3,....,98,99\right\}$.The number $b$ is selected from the same set.What is the probability that the number $3^a+7^b$ has a digit equal to $8$ at the units place?

---

I only know this much that $3^a+7^b(mod 10)=8$.When $3^a+7^b$ is divided by $10$,its remainder is $8$ because its unit place is $1.$Total number of cases$=100\times 100$,but i cannot count favorable number of cases.Hence could not find the probability.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $3^a+7^b=8$ mod $10$ iff $(a,b)=(2,2)$ or $(3,0)$ or $(0,1)$ mod $4$.

Comment: How did you find out these values?By hit and trial or some concrete method?@Did

Comment: I wrote down the congruences of the powers of 3 mod 10, these are 1, 3, 9, 7, those of the powers of 7 mod 10, these are 1, 7, 9, 3, and I computed the couples whose sum is 8 mod 10, namely (1,7), (7,1) and (9,9).

Comment: @Did,i got it.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Chinese theorem. $\equiv 8\pmod{10}$  means even and $\equiv 3\pmod{5}$. Now both $3$ and $7\equiv 2$ are generators for $\mathbb{F}_5^*$, hence the working cases are $a\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ and $b\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, $a\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and $b\equiv 0\pmod{4}$, $a\equiv 0\pmod{4}$ and $b\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. $3^a$ and $7^b$ are always odd, hence $3^a+7^b$ is always $\equiv 0\pmod{2}$. Since the residue classes $\pmod{4}$ are equidistributed in $\{0,1,2,\ldots,98,99\}$, the wanted probability is:
$$ \frac{3\cdot 25\cdot 25}{100\cdot 100}=\color{red}{\frac{3}{16}}.$$

Comment: I understood how you got the favourable cases however ... For Finding probability in the denominator we want the *Total numbers that can be generated* by putting in different values of $a,b$ .Now I understand why you say it is $100*100$ {as there are 100 possible  values of both $a$ and $b$ } However does it necessarily mean that all numbers generated on putting different values of $a,b$ are *All different* why can't there be a case where $$3^{a_1}+7^{b_1}=3^{a_2}+7^{b_2}$$ and $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ belong to $\left\{0,1,2,3,....,98,99\right\}$. and $a_1 \ne a_2$ and $b_1 \ne b_2$

Comment: As in this case Total Numbers generated In the denominator Will not be equal to $100*100$ and the answer will change.